# Is AmazonAWS creating non-genuine hits? How can I verify?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, web

I have a site that logs a "hit (via saving a record to a Hits table that captures the date/time and IP of the machine whenever the detail page is loaded)" whenever a user brings up a detail page for a particular item so that admins can see how many hits that particular item gets. We get random instances where items are being hit multiple times/day in twos. So, in the data, it looks like a user is viewing an item, but the site is logging their hit twice in the database (same item, same date/time, same IP Address, etc.). Most hits are only being recorded once, and all my testing has lead to assurance the site is working appropriately. I'm noticing that particular IP Addresses are causing double hits. When I do Reverse IP searches, all the "double hits" are tied to IP Addresses that trace back to Amazonaws in northern Virginia, on the other side of the country. Our site is used locally, and the single hits are coming from IPs that trace back to local areas. Is there a bot hitting my site from afar? Should I block Amazonaws in Azure (which is where my site is hosted) or is that going to lock out genuine users? Is there a way I can detect whether a hit is genuine in my code (my site is in .Net MVC)? Has anyone faced a similar situation in the past?

Note: This IS RELEVANT to software engineering because a part of the question is asking how I can verify in my code that a hit is genuine!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Even Google Chrome will hit your site twice. While you are typing the url of your site Google Chrome will immediately hit your site to prefetch the page. Once you hit enter Google Chrome will hit your site again to load the page, there you go.. double hits. If you don't believe me try it.. and don't ask me why.. it is how it is...

Comment: No, because if I run through the process of loading an item in my browser, it only records one hit in the table.  Hits are being logged in the controller when the page is loaded.  ActionResult methods that load a page are only run once.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what I found out (no thanks to the elitist user who downvoted my question and offered no contribution) is that, my hit counter is being inflated by web crawlers.  The quick and dirty solution is to implement a robots.txt file to block crawlers from hitting that page.  Of course, that comes with the sacrifice that my client's site will no longer come up, should the public do a google search for the product being offered.

One alternative is the hidden link method; in which we put a hidden page on the site that no human user would ever access.  When a bot hits that page, we record the IP in a "blacklist" table.  Then, before our real hit counter logs a hit, it checks the user's IP against the blacklist.

Another alternative is to implement a blacklist of known User-Agents used by bots.  We check the user's credentials against that list in order to determine whether a user is a bot.

Neither of these solutions are 100% though.

These are fairly adequate responses to my question.  Of course, since this is StackExchange (or StackOverflow or StackYourMomma or whatever it is), people are just going to downvote your question and act like you're beneath a response because you didn't follow all the little bull crap rules that come along with being a member of the SE/SO/SYM community.